# Google Sheets - Sending email based on specific sheet in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to Google Scripts so I'm bumping my head on this entry level code. I want to send an email based on a specific sheet in a spreadsheet. The tab or sheet is named 'Test 2'. Currently this is my code.

```
/* Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.*/
    function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
      var dataRange = getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2); // Fetch the range of cells A2:B6
      var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        var message = row[1]; // Second column
        var subject = 'THIS IS A TEST';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
    }
```

And right now it's throwing this error.

```
ReferenceError: "getRange" is not defined. (line 8, file "Code")
```

How can I get it to run while referencing that sheet 'Test 2'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to avoid the error of `"getRange" is not defined.`.
- You want to retrieve the values from the cell "A2:B6" of the sheet `Test 2`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var dataRange = getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
```

#### To:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getSheetByName("Test 2").getRange("A2:B6");
```

#### Note:

- In this case, at first, retrieve the sheet object of `Test 2` and use the method of `getRange` for the sheet object.
- I thought that a1Notation might be suitable for your situation.

#### Reference:

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for helping me out, this saved me a lot of time, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mac Grossman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.